# Std::pair/ostringstream ctor syntax

Tags: c++, stdstring, ostream, std-pair, ostringstream

Why does the following code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> pair1((std::ostringstream().flush() << "hello").str(), (std::ostringstream().flush() << "world").str());
    return 0;
}
```

... generate the compiler error...

```
>g++ main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7: error: ‘struct std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >’ has no member named ‘str’
main.cpp:7: error: ‘struct std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >’ has no member named ‘str’
```

...whereas the code below does not generate any compiler error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss1;
    std::ostringstream oss2;
    oss1 << "hello";
    oss2 << "world";
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> pair1(oss1.str(), oss2.str());
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone can advise how to, I would ideally like to pull off a "one-line" creation and population of my std::pair, as I'm attempting to do in the first code block. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) function you're using to write the string literals takes a `basic_ostream&` and returns a `basic_ostream&`. But [`str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) is a member of `basic_ostringstream`, so you cannot invoke it on a `basic_ostream&`.

You could cast the return value, and your code would compile

```
static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream().flush() << "hello")).str()
```

Also, since `flush`ing a default constructed `stringstream` is pointless, you should get rid of that.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer, though, gives me concern about downcasting a basic_ostream to a basic_ostringstream. Is this considered safe because the basic_ostream& returned by operator<< is actually the very same rvalue ostringstream upon which it is invoked?

Comment: @StoneThrow The returned `ostream&` refers to the base class instance of the `ostringstream` instance you constructed, so it's absolutely safe to cast it back to the original type.